# Como retornar com um alert de erro, quando não digitarem um valor na variável?

Tags: javascript

Estava fazendo alguns exercícios para praticar JavaScript, quando me deparei com uma duvida, como faço para disparar um alert de erro quando pelo menos uma das variáveis recebe uma string ou nenhum valor?

Esse foi o código que eu criei.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Diferença</title>
    <style>
        body{
            font: normal 80px Arial;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        var A = Number.parseInt(window.prompt('Digite o valor de A:'))
        var B = Number.parseInt(window.prompt('Digite o valor de B:'))
        var C = Number.parseInt(window.prompt('Digite o valor de C:'))
        var D = Number.parseInt(window.prompt('Digite o valor de D:'))
        var dif = (A*B)-(C*D)
        document.write(`DIFERENÇA = ${dif}`)
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Além do `isNaN` você deve comparar também com string vazia `if (a === '')`, pois quando o usuário não digita nada, este valor é uma string vazia.